# Divide value in JS Input field and calculate

Tags: javascript, calc

I am newbie and I am trying to build a calculator of costs. 
On the input field 3, I would like the value divides by 80. So if user entres 80 as a value, it will count 1. If 81 is entered, it will then count 2 and so forth. 
Can you please help?

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <script>
    function updatesum() {
    document.input.total.value = (document.input.input1.value -0) * (document.input.input2.value -0) * (document.input.input3value -0);
    return false;
        }
    </script>
    <body>      
<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
Calculator<br>
Value1:<input type="text" name="input1" value=" "><br>
Value2:<input type="text" name="input2" value="2"><br>
Value3:<input type="text" name="input3" value=" "><br>
Costs:<input type="text" name="total" value=" ">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="updatesum()">
</form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_%28%29)

Comment: But 81 / 80 != 2. Do you mean, round up to the nearest 80?

Comment: Hi, not exactly. I mean that 80=1, 81=2, and so on. I want to multiply the value by the number of units it goes above 80 and everytime in 80, 160, etc... numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final answer (Tested OK).

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updatesum() {
        document.input.total.value = Math.ceil(document.input.input1.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input2.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input3.value / 80);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
        Calculator<br>
        Value1:<input type="text" name="input1" value=""><br>
        Value2:<input type="text" name="input2" value="2"><br>
        Value3:<input type="text" name="input3" value=""><br>
        Costs:<input type="text" name="total" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="updatesum()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, thank you for your prompt answer. Unfortunately it won't return anything upon "submit". Just nocthing happens... :-(

Comment: Thank you Ankit, it works now!! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return false;">
            Calculator<br>
            Value1:<input type="text" name="input1" value=""><br>
            Value2:<input type="text" name="input2" value="2"><br>
            Value3:<input type="text" name="input3" onblur="calcVal()" value=""><br>
            Costs:<input type="text" name="total" value="">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="updatesum()">
        </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatesum() {
            document.input.total.value = Math.ceil(document.input.input1.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input2.value / 80) * Math.ceil(document.input.input3.value / 80);
            return false;
        }

        function calcVal() {
           document.input.input3.value = Math.round(document.input.input3.value / 80) + 1;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```